# How to display property value linked by nested reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Not sure if what I am trying to do is possible.

I want to display the value of the 'name' property in my user schema (model) by retrieving data from an article document that references the comment schema (model) that references the user schema (model).

'article' references 'comment' which references 'user' that holds 'user.name' value that I want to retrieve.

My controller code to retrieve article by ID data and populate the 'author' and 'comments' fields looks like this:

```
    Article.findById(req.params.id)
      .populate('author')
      .populate('comments')
      .exec(function(err, article){
         if(err){
            return req.flash('error', 'Unable to display article.');
         } else {
            res.render('articles/show', {
               article: article
            });
         }
     });
```

My article schema (model) includes a 'comments' property like this:

```
  ... 
  comments: [
      {
         type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
      }
   ],
   ...
```

My comment schema (model) includes an 'author' property like this:

```
   ...
   text: String,
   author:
   {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"   
   },
   ...
```

The user schema (model) has the 'name' property that holds the value that I want to display in my view (EJS).

So, far I have been unable to find a way to display it, maybe because I can't do it without another query.

I loop through the 'article.comments' array and successfully display the comment text with `<%= comment.text %>` but I cannot figure out a way to display the 'name' property from the 'user' schema (model) referenced in the comment schema (model).

I would appreciate any insight as to my error(s).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. What you're trying to do is deep population.

Simply do

```
Article.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: 'comments',
    populate: {
        path: 'author'
    }
}).exec(function(err, article){
    if (err)
        return req.flash('error', 'Unable to display article.');
    res.render('articles/show', { article: article });
});
```

In your view, for each comment, you would do something like

```
<%- comment.author.name %>
```

For more information, check out this [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate).

Comment: Thanks Mikey. Implemented and getting error: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" I can display `comment.text` and `comment._id` but not property from the user schema referenced in 'comment.author'

Answer (score 0):

You have to do deep population

`Article.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: 'article',
    populate:{
        path: 'comments',
        populate: {
            path: 'user'
        }
    }
}).exec(function(err, article){
    if (err)
        return req.flash('error', 'Unable to display article.');
    res.render('articles/show', { article: article });
});`

Comment: Thanks Ayush. I am getting the same error: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". Is the value of path the property in the schema or the model name? The model names are article, comment and user. The properties are 'article.comments', 'comment.author', and 'user.name'.

Comment: @Jimv814 you have to put the field name that you want to populate.

Answer (score 0):

Additional research on deep population didn't produce an answer for me. Here's what I did.

I modified my Comment schema and created 'id', 'username' & 'name' properties/fields like this:

```
....
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
var commentSchema = new Schema({
   text: String,
   author: {
      id:
      {
         type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"    
      },
      username: String, 
      name: String      
   },
   ....
```

Perhaps a DRY violation, but it lets me get the data I need to display.

My query that populates the comments and author fields:

```
Article.findById(req.params.id)
   .populate('comments')
   .populate('author')
   .exec(function(err, article){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
         return req.flash('error', 'Unable to display article.');
      } else {
         res.render('articles/show', {
            article: article
         });
      }
   });
```

I suspect that deep population holds the best answer but time sometimes forces us to move on. Hopefully, this might help someone in a similar situation. Thanks to Mikey and Ayush for their help.